# #R shiny non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a problem more reactive to new inputs here is where the error is given

```
Pwh_Design=reactive((input$Pwh+0.2*(input$Pso-input$Pwh)))

Gtd=Pwh_Design-P_operating_point_formation/(0-D_operating_point)
```

this is in the server.

the entire app:

UI:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("OTIS Gas Lift"),
fluidRow(column(width = 6,
                numericInput(inputId = "Dmax",label = "Depth to mid perforation",value = 7500),
                numericInput("Pwh","Pwh",100),
                numericInput("Tres","Tres",182),
                numericInput("Pso","P Casing at Surface",870),
                numericInput("Psc","P Casing at Depth D1",1050),
                numericInput("D1","D1",7000),
                numericInput("P_across_valve","P_across_valve",100),
                numericInput("GL","Load Grad",0.5),
                numericInput("Pwf","Pwf",1760),
                numericInput("RGOR","Required GOR",400)
                ),
         column(width = 6,
         numericInput("FGOR","Formation GOR",200),
         numericInput("Twh","Twh",100),
         numericInput("Pko","kill pressure at Surface",920),
         numericInput("Pk","Kill Pressure at D2",1100),
         numericInput("D2","D2",7000),
         numericInput("T_inj","T_inj",100),
         numericInput("q","Desired Production Rate STB/d",600),
         numericInput("R","R",0.1534),
         numericInput("Gf","Flowing Grad before inj",0.4)
         )),
fluidRow(submitButton(text = "Apply Changes",width = "100%")),
splitLayout(tableOutput(outputId = "table"),plotOutput(outputId = "plot"))))
```

'''

This is the server

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    Dmax=reactiveValues()       #to mid perforation ft

#one of those two next must be given

FGOR=reactiveValues()          #scf/STB Formation GOR
Pwh=reactiveValues()           #psig
Twh=reactiveValues()           #degree fahrenheit
Tres=reactiveValues()          #degree fahrenheit

#casing and kill gradients
Pso=reactiveValues()           #psig
Pcs=reactiveValues()          #psig at 7000ft
D1=reactiveValues()           #ft
Pko=reactiveValues()           #psig
Pk=reactiveValues()            #psig at 7000ft
D2=reactiveValues()           #ft

P_across_valve=reactiveValues()          #psig
T_inj=reactiveValues()         #degree fahrenheit
GL=reactiveValues()           #load gradient (kill fluid grad)
q=reactiveValues()    
Pwf=reactiveValues()          #psi or BHP
RGOR=reactiveValues()          #scf/STB required GOR
R=reactiveValues()

Gf=reactiveValues()            #flowing gradient before injection default value

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#plot basics
plot<-reactive(ggplot+
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,input$Pwf+500))+
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")+
    scale_x_continuous(position = "top"))


#Flowing Gradient
#slope Gf
#point (pwf,Dmax)
#get p1 at depth 4000ft
p1=reactive(input$Pwf-input$Gf*(input$Dmax-4000))
flowing_gradient<-reactive(data.frame(D=c(4000,input$Dmax),P=c(p1,input$Pwf)))

plot0<-plot+
    geom_point(data = flowing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D))+
    geom_line(data = flowing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D))



#casing gradient
casing_gradient<-reactive(data.frame(D=c(0,input$D1),P=c(input$Pso,input$Pcs)))

plot1<-plot0+geom_point(data=casing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D))+
    geom_line(data=casing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D))

Gc=reactive((input$Pso-input$Pcs)/(0-input$D1))

#killing gradient
killing_gradient<-reactive(data.frame(D=c(0,input$D2),P=c(input$Pko,input$Pk)))

plot2<-plot1+geom_point(data=killing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D))+
    geom_line(data=killing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D))
Gk=reactive((input$Pko-input$Pk)/(0-input$D2))

#balance point
d1=reactive((input$Pwf-input$Pso-input$Gf*input$Dmax)/(Gc-input$Gf))
d_balance_point=d1


#operating_point
d1=reactive((input$Pso-input$Pwf+input$Gf*input$Dmax-input$P_across_valve)/(input$Gf-Gc))
D_operating_point=d1

P_operating_point_casing=reactive(input$Pso+D_operating_point*Gc)
P_operating_point_formation=reactive(input$Pwf-input$Gf*(input$Dmax-D_operating_point))

plot3<-plot2+geom_point(aes(x=P_operating_point_formation,y=D_operating_point))


#Tubing grad
tubing_grad<-reactive(data.frame(D=c(0,D_operating_point),P=c(input$Pwh,P_operating_point_formation)))


plot4<-plot3+geom_point(data = tubing_grad,aes(x=P,y=D))+
    geom_line(data = tubing_grad,aes(x=P,y=D))


#Tubing_design_grad
Pwh_Design=reactive((input$Pwh+0.2*(input$Pso-input$Pwh)))

Gtd=Pwh_Design-P_operating_point_formation/(0-D_operating_point)        #Tubing design grad
tubing_design_grad<-data.frame(D=c(0,D_operating_point),P=c(Pwh_Design,P_operating_point_formation))

plot5<-plot4+geom_point(data = tubing_design_grad,aes(x=P,y=D))+
    geom_line(data = tubing_design_grad,aes(x=P,y=D))


#first valve
D_valve1=reactive((input$Pwh-input$Pko)/(Gk-input$GL))

PK_valve1=reactive(D_valve1*Gk+input$Pko)

PTD_valve1=Gtd*D_valve1+Pwh_Design

df<-reactive(data.frame(D=c(0,D_valve1),P=c(input$Pwh,PK_valve1)))
#ploting
plot6<-plot5+geom_point(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))+
    geom_line(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))

df<-data.frame(D=c(D_valve1,D_valve1),P=c(PTD_valve1,PK_valve1))

plot7<-plot6+geom_point(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))+
    geom_line(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))

plot<-plot7

Final_table<-data.frame(depth=D_valve1,
                        Pc=PK_valve1,
                        Pt=PTD_valve1)

dvalve=D_valve1
PTDvalve=PTD_valve1
Pcvalve=PK_valve1
D_valve=D_valve1
PTD_valve=PTD_valve1


while (dvalve<D_operating_point) {
    dvalve=reactive((PTDvalve-input$Pso-dvalve*input$GL)/(Gc-input$GL))
    Pcvalve=reactive(input$Pso+Gc*dvalve)
    if(dvalve<D_operating_point){
        df<-data.frame(D=c(D_valve,dvalve),P=c(PTD_valve,Pcvalve))
        plot<-plot+geom_point(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))+
            geom_line(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))
        
        PTDvalve=Gtd*dvalve+Pwh_Design
        
        df<-data.frame(D=c(dvalve,dvalve),P=c(PTDvalve,Pcvalve))
        plot<-plot+geom_point(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))+
            geom_line(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))
        
        
        valve<-c(dvalve,Pcvalve,PTDvalve)
        Final_table<-rbind(Final_table,valve)
        D_valve=dvalve
        PTD_valve=PTDvalve
    }}

output$plot<-renderPlot(plot)

valve<-c(D_operating_point,P_operating_point_casing,P_operating_point_formation)
Final_table<-rbind(Final_table,valve)


GTemp=reactive((input$Tres-input$Twh)/input$Dmax)

CT_data<-data.frame(Temp=c(61:300),Ct=c(0.998,0.996,0.994,0.991,0.989,0.987,0.985,0.983,0.981,0.979,0.977,0.975,0.973,0.971,0.969,0.967,0.965,0.963,0.961,0.959,0.957,0.955,0.953,0.951,0.949,0.947,0.945,0.943,0.941,0.939,0.938,0.936,0.934,0.932,0.93,0.928,0.926,0.924,0.923,0.921,0.919,0.917,0.915,0.914,0.912,0.91,0.908,0.906,0.905,0.903,0.901,0.899,0.898,0.896,0.894,0.893,0.891,0.889,0.887,0.886,0.884,0.882,0.881,0.879,0.877,0.876,0.874,0.872,0.871,0.869,0.686,0.866,0.864,0.863,0.861,0.86,0.858,0.856,0.855,0.853,0.852,0.85,0.849,0.847,0.845,0.844,0.842,0.841,0.839,0.838,0.836,0.835,0.833,0.832,0.83,0.829,0.827,0.826,0.825,0.823,0.822,0.82,0.819,0.817,0.816,0.814,0.813,0.812,0.81,0.809,0.807,0.806,0.805,0.803,0.802,0.8,0.799,0.798,0.796,0.795,0.794,0.792,0.791,0.79,0.788,0.787,0.786,0.784,0.783,0.782,0.78,0.779,0.778,0.776,0.775,0.774,0.772,0.771,0.77,0.769,0.767,0.766,0.765,0.764,0.762,0.761,0.76,0.759,0.757,0.756,0.755,0.754,0.752,0.751,0.75,0.749,0.748,0.746,0.745,0.744,0.743,0.742,0.74,0.739,0.738,0.737,0.736,0.735,0.733,0.732,0.731,0.73,0.729,0.728,0.727,0.725,0.724,0.723,0.722,0.721,0.72,0.719,0.718,0.717,0.715,0.714,0.713,0.712,0.711,0.71,0.709,0.708,0.707,0.706,0.705,0.704,0.702,0.701,0.7,0.699,0.698,0.697,0.696,0.695,0.694,0.693,0.692,0.691,0.69,0.689,0.688,0.687,0.686,0.685,0.684,0.683,0.682,0.681,0.68,0.679,0.678,0.677,0.676,0.675,0.674,0.673,0.672,0.671,0.67,0.699,0.668,0.667,0.666,0.665,0.664,0.663,0.662,0.662,0.661,0.66))


Final_table<-Final_table %>% mutate(reactive(Pbt=input$Pc*(1-input$R)+Pt*input$R),
                                    reactive(TEMP=input$Twh+GTemp*depth),
                                    Temp=ceiling(TEMP))
Final_table<-merge(x=Final_table,y=CT_data,by = "Temp",all.x = T)
Final_table<-Final_table%>%select(depth,Pc,Pt,Pbt,TEMP,Ct)

Final_table<-Final_table %>% mutate(Pb=Pbt*Ct,
                                    Pvo=reactive(Pb/(1-input$R)))
output$table<-tableOutput(Final_table)})
```

I tried making any variable with reactive assignment included in () but it gives this error4

"Warning: Error in : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.

- You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.
  58: 
  Error : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
- You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer."

I am pretty sure i did it to only the reactive assigned variables when recalling them

****EDIT****

After I tried to solve the problem it gives:

Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
1: runApp

whenever I press the action button
the new server

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
plot<-reactiveVal(NULL)
Final_table<-reactiveVal(data.frame())

observeEvent(input$submit,{
    plot(ggplot()+
             coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,input$Pwf+500))+
             scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")+
             scale_x_continuous(position = "top"))
    
    #Flowing Gradient
    #slope Gf
    #point (pwf,Dmax)
    #get p1 at depth 4000ft
    p1=input$Pwf-input$Gf*(input$Dmax-4000)
    flowing_gradient<-data.frame(D=c(4000,input$Dmax),P=c(p1,input$Pwf))
    
    plot(plot()+
             geom_point(data = flowing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D))+
             geom_line(data = flowing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D)))
    
    
    
    #casing gradient
    casing_gradient<-data.frame(D=c(0,input$D1),P=c(input$Pso,input$Pcs))
    
    plot(plot()+geom_point(data=casing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D))+
             geom_line(data=casing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D)))
    
    Gc=(input$Pso-input$Pcs)/(0-input$D1)
    
    #killing gradient
    killing_gradient<-data.frame(D=c(0,input$D2),P=c(input$Pko,input$Pk))
    
    plot(plot()+geom_point(data=killing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D))+
             geom_line(data=killing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D)))
    Gk=(input$Pko-input$Pk)/(0-input$D2)
    
    #balance point
    d1=(input$Pwf-input$Pso-input$Gf*input$Dmax)/(Gc-input$Gf)
    d_balance_point=d1
    
    
    #operating_point
    d1=(input$Pso-input$Pwf+input$Gf*input$Dmax-input$P_across_valve)/(input$Gf-Gc)
    D_operating_point=d1
    
    P_operating_point_casing=input$Pso+D_operating_point*Gc
    P_operating_point_formation=input$Pwf-input$Gf*(input$Dmax-D_operating_point)
    
    plot(plot()+geom_point(aes(x=P_operating_point_formation,y=D_operating_point)))
    
    
    #Tubing grad
    tubing_grad<-data.frame(D=c(0,D_operating_point),P=c(input$Pwh,P_operating_point_formation))
    
    
    plot(plot()+geom_point(data = tubing_grad,aes(x=P,y=D))+
             geom_line(data = tubing_grad,aes(x=P,y=D)))
    
    
    #Tubing_design_grad
    Pwh_design=input$Pwh+0.2*(input$Pso-input$Pwh)
    
    Gtd=(Pwh_design-P_operating_point_formation)/(0-D_operating_point)        #Tubing design grad
    tubing_design_grad<-data.frame(D=c(0,D_operating_point),P=c(Pwh_design,P_operating_point_formation))
    
    plot(plot()+geom_point(data = tubing_design_grad,aes(x=P,y=D))+
             geom_line(data = tubing_design_grad,aes(x=P,y=D)))
    
    
    #first valve
    D_valve1=(input$Pwh-input$Pko)/(Gk-input$GL)
    
    PK_valve1=D_valve1*Gk+input$Pko
    
    PTD_valve1=Gtd*D_valve1+Pwh_design
    
    df<-data.frame(D=c(0,D_valve1),P=c(input$Pwh,PK_valve1))
    #ploting
    plot(plot()+geom_point(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))+
             geom_line(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D)))
    
    df<-data.frame(D=c(D_valve1,D_valve1),P=c(PTD_valve1,PK_valve1))
    
    plot(plot()+geom_point(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))+
             geom_line(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D)))
    
    
    
    
    Final_table(data.frame(depth=D_valve1,
                           Pc=PK_valve1,
                           Pt=PTD_valve1))
    
    dvalve=D_valve1
    PTDvalve=PTD_valve1
    Pcvalve=PK_valve1
    D_valve=D_valve1
    PTD_valve=PTD_valve1
    
    
    while (dvalve<D_operating_point) {
        dvalve=(PTDvalve-input$Pso-dvalve*input$GL)/(Gc-input$GL)
        Pcvalve=input$Pso+Gc*dvalve
        if(dvalve<D_operating_point){
            df<-data.frame(D=c(D_valve,dvalve),P=c(PTD_valve,Pcvalve))
            plot(plot()+geom_point(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))+
                     geom_line(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D)))
            
            PTDvalve=Gtd*dvalve+Pwh_design
            
            df<-data.frame(D=c(dvalve,dvalve),P=c(PTDvalve,Pcvalve))
            plot(plot()+geom_point(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D))+
                     geom_line(data = df, aes(x=P,y=D)))
            
            
            valve<-c(dvalve,Pcvalve,PTDvalve)
            Final_table(rbind(Final_table(),valve))
            D_valve=dvalve
            PTD_valve=PTDvalve
        }}
    
    valve<-c(D_operating_point,P_operating_point_casing,P_operating_point_formation)
    Final_table(rbind(Final_table(),valve))
    
    
    GTemp=(input$Tres-input$Twh)/input$Dmax
    
    CT_data<-data.frame(Temp=c(61:300),Ct=c(0.998,0.996,0.994,0.991,0.989,0.987,0.985,0.983,0.981,0.979,0.977,0.975,0.973,0.971,0.969,0.967,0.965,0.963,0.961,0.959,0.957,0.955,0.953,0.951,0.949,0.947,0.945,0.943,0.941,0.939,0.938,0.936,0.934,0.932,0.93,0.928,0.926,0.924,0.923,0.921,0.919,0.917,0.915,0.914,0.912,0.91,0.908,0.906,0.905,0.903,0.901,0.899,0.898,0.896,0.894,0.893,0.891,0.889,0.887,0.886,0.884,0.882,0.881,0.879,0.877,0.876,0.874,0.872,0.871,0.869,0.686,0.866,0.864,0.863,0.861,0.86,0.858,0.856,0.855,0.853,0.852,0.85,0.849,0.847,0.845,0.844,0.842,0.841,0.839,0.838,0.836,0.835,0.833,0.832,0.83,0.829,0.827,0.826,0.825,0.823,0.822,0.82,0.819,0.817,0.816,0.814,0.813,0.812,0.81,0.809,0.807,0.806,0.805,0.803,0.802,0.8,0.799,0.798,0.796,0.795,0.794,0.792,0.791,0.79,0.788,0.787,0.786,0.784,0.783,0.782,0.78,0.779,0.778,0.776,0.775,0.774,0.772,0.771,0.77,0.769,0.767,0.766,0.765,0.764,0.762,0.761,0.76,0.759,0.757,0.756,0.755,0.754,0.752,0.751,0.75,0.749,0.748,0.746,0.745,0.744,0.743,0.742,0.74,0.739,0.738,0.737,0.736,0.735,0.733,0.732,0.731,0.73,0.729,0.728,0.727,0.725,0.724,0.723,0.722,0.721,0.72,0.719,0.718,0.717,0.715,0.714,0.713,0.712,0.711,0.71,0.709,0.708,0.707,0.706,0.705,0.704,0.702,0.701,0.7,0.699,0.698,0.697,0.696,0.695,0.694,0.693,0.692,0.691,0.69,0.689,0.688,0.687,0.686,0.685,0.684,0.683,0.682,0.681,0.68,0.679,0.678,0.677,0.676,0.675,0.674,0.673,0.672,0.671,0.67,0.699,0.668,0.667,0.666,0.665,0.664,0.663,0.662,0.662,0.661,0.66))
    
    
    Final_table(Final_table() %>% mutate(Pbt=Pc*(1-input$R)+Pt*input$R,
                                         TEMP=input$Twh+GTemp*depth,
                                         Temp=ceiling(TEMP)))
    Final_table(merge(x=Final_table(),y=CT_data,by = "Temp",all.x = T))
    Final_table(Final_table()%>%select(depth,Pc,Pt,Pbt,TEMP,Ct))
    
    Final_table(Final_table() %>% mutate(Pb=Pbt*Ct,
                                         Pvo=Pb/(1-input$R)))
})

output$plot<-renderPlot({
    isolate(plot())
})

output$table<-renderTable({
    isolate(Final_table())
})

})
```

Comment: If you define a reactive value, say, `df <- reactive({iris})`. To be able to use it you need to call it like a function, inside a reactive context. For example `observe({ df() })`. You  dragged that mistake through the entire app.  Also, you can greatly reduce the amount of `reactive`'s by passing an expression to either `observe` or `reactive`.  For example, `x <- reactive({local_var <- input$someid  print(local_var))})`

Comment: @jpdugo17 sorry for the inconvenience but this is my first time using reactivity in my app and it seems I didn't comprehend it very well can u please point a reference that explains the concept u pointing at clearly that would be very helpful thanks in advance

Comment: Yes of course, I added an answer to create the first plot, you can follow that pattern for every plot, notice the use of `reactiveVal`, it is a similar concept as `reactive`. For more information of reactivity you can read [Reactivity - an Overview](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help I will go through the source u mentioned and the code to fully understand it
Thanks again for ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a MRE up to the first `plot` to ilustrate how to deal with reactive objects. Notice the use of () when accessing a reactive value.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("OTIS Gas Lift"),
    fluidRow(column(width = 6,
                    numericInput(inputId = "Dmax",label = "Depth to mid perforation",value = 7500),
                    numericInput("Pwh","Pwh",100),
                    numericInput("Tres","Tres",182),
                    numericInput("Pso","P Casing at Surface",870),
                    numericInput("Psc","P Casing at Depth D1",1050),
                    numericInput("D1","D1",7000),
                    numericInput("P_across_valve","P_across_valve",100),
                    numericInput("GL","Load Grad",0.5),
                    numericInput("Pwf","Pwf",1760),
                    numericInput("RGOR","Required GOR",400)
    ),
    column(width = 6,
           numericInput("FGOR","Formation GOR",200),
           numericInput("Twh","Twh",100),
           numericInput("Pko","kill pressure at Surface",920),
           numericInput("Pk","Kill Pressure at D2",1100),
           numericInput("D2","D2",7000),
           numericInput("T_inj","T_inj",100),
           numericInput("q","Desired Production Rate STB/d",600),
           numericInput("R","R",0.1534),
           numericInput("Gf","Flowing Grad before inj",0.4)
    )),
    fluidRow(actionButton('submit' ,label = "Apply Changes",width = "100%")),
    splitLayout(tableOutput(outputId = "table"),plotOutput(outputId = "plot"))
    )


library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    #define plot object that can be accessed inside of reactive() or observe()
    plot_rv <- reactiveVal(NULL) 
    flowing_gradient_rv <- reactiveVal(NULL)

    #inside this observer we can create regular local objects (only accesible inside the observer) like when creating functions.
    #notice the code wrapped in curly braces {} to be able to pass multiple lines of code into `observeEvent()` second argument.
    #input$submit corresponds to the action button created in the ui.
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
        
    plot_rv(ggplot() +
        coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, input$Pwf + 500)) +
        scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse") +
        scale_x_continuous(position = "top"))
    
    
    #Flowing Gradient
    #slope Gf
    #point (pwf,Dmax)
    #get p1 at depth 4000ft
    
    #input values are now available without calling reactive since we already are "inside" the observer
    p1 <- input$Pwf - input$Gf * (input$Dmax - 4000)
    flowing_gradient <- data.frame(D = c(4000, input$Dmax), P = c(p1, input$Pwf))
    
    #to use flowing_gradient outside this observer we use flowing_gradient reactiveVal
    flowing_gradient_rv(flowing_gradient)
    
    
    plot_rv(plot_rv() +
        geom_point(data = flowing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D))+
        geom_line(data = flowing_gradient,aes(x=P,y=D))
    )
    
    })
    
    #to show the plots
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        plot_rv()
    })
    
    output$table <- renderTable(
        flowing_gradient_rv()
    )
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit: The edited app currently working.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("OTIS Gas Lift"),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 6,
      numericInput(inputId = "Dmax", label = "Depth to mid perforation", value = 7500),
      numericInput("Pwh", "Pwh", 100),
      numericInput("Tres", "Tres", 182),
      numericInput("Pso", "P Casing at Surface", 870),
      numericInput("Psc", "P Casing at Depth D1", 1050),
      numericInput("D1", "D1", 7000),
      numericInput("P_across_valve", "P_across_valve", 100),
      numericInput("GL", "Load Grad", 0.5),
      numericInput("Pwf", "Pwf", 1760),
      numericInput("RGOR", "Required GOR", 400)
    ),
    column(
      width = 6,
      numericInput("FGOR", "Formation GOR", 200),
      numericInput("Twh", "Twh", 100),
      numericInput("Pko", "kill pressure at Surface", 920),
      numericInput("Pk", "Kill Pressure at D2", 1100),
      numericInput("D2", "D2", 7000),
      numericInput("T_inj", "T_inj", 100),
      numericInput("q", "Desired Production Rate STB/d", 600),
      numericInput("R", "R", 0.1534),
      numericInput("Gf", "Flowing Grad before inj", 0.4)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(actionButton("submit", label = "Apply Changes", width = "100%")),
  splitLayout(tableOutput(outputId = "table"), plotOutput(outputId = "plot"))
)


library(shiny)

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
server <- function(input, output) {
  plot <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  Final_table <- reactiveVal(data.frame())

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    plot(ggplot() +
      coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, input$Pwf + 500)) +
      scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse") +
      scale_x_continuous(position = "top"))

    # Flowing Gradient
    # slope Gf
    # point (pwf,Dmax)
    # get p1 at depth 4000ft
    p1 <- input$Pwf - input$Gf * (input$Dmax - 4000)
    flowing_gradient <- data.frame(D = c(4000, input$Dmax), P = c(p1, input$Pwf))

    plot(plot() +
      geom_point(data = flowing_gradient, aes(x = P, y = D)) +
      geom_line(data = flowing_gradient, aes(x = P, y = D)))



    # casing gradient
    casing_gradient <- data.frame(D = c(0, input$D1), P = c(input$Pso, input$Pcs))

    plot(plot() + geom_point(data = casing_gradient, aes(x = P, y = D)) +
      geom_line(data = casing_gradient, aes(x = P, y = D)))

    Gc <- (input$Pso - input$Psc) / (0 - input$D1)
    

    # killing gradient
    killing_gradient <- data.frame(D = c(0, input$D2), P = c(input$Pko, input$Pk))

    plot(plot() + geom_point(data = killing_gradient, aes(x = P, y = D)) +
      geom_line(data = killing_gradient, aes(x = P, y = D)))
    Gk <- (input$Pko - input$Pk) / (0 - input$D2)

    # balance point
    d1 <- (input$Pwf - input$Pso - input$Gf * input$Dmax) / (Gc - input$Gf)
    
    d_balance_point <- d1
    
    

    
    # operating_point
    d1 <- (input$Pso - input$Pwf + input$Gf * input$Dmax - input$P_across_valve) / (input$Gf - Gc)
    D_operating_point <- d1
    
    

    P_operating_point_casing <- input$Pso + D_operating_point * Gc
    P_operating_point_formation <- input$Pwf - input$Gf * (input$Dmax - D_operating_point)

    plot(plot() + geom_point(aes(x = P_operating_point_formation, y = D_operating_point)))


    # Tubing grad
    tubing_grad <- data.frame(D = c(0, D_operating_point), P = c(input$Pwh, P_operating_point_formation))


    plot(plot() + geom_point(data = tubing_grad, aes(x = P, y = D)) +
      geom_line(data = tubing_grad, aes(x = P, y = D)))


    # Tubing_design_grad
    Pwh_design <- input$Pwh + 0.2 * (input$Pso - input$Pwh)

    Gtd <- (Pwh_design - P_operating_point_formation) / (0 - D_operating_point)# Tubing design grad
    
    tubing_design_grad <- data.frame(D = c(0, D_operating_point), P = c(Pwh_design, P_operating_point_formation))

    plot(plot() + geom_point(data = tubing_design_grad, aes(x = P, y = D)) +
      geom_line(data = tubing_design_grad, aes(x = P, y = D)))


    # first valve
    D_valve1 <- (input$Pwh - input$Pko) / (Gk - input$GL)

    PK_valve1 <- D_valve1 * Gk + input$Pko

    PTD_valve1 <- Gtd * D_valve1 + Pwh_design
    

    df <- data.frame(D = c(0, D_valve1), P = c(input$Pwh, PK_valve1))
    # ploting
    plot(plot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = P, y = D)) +
      geom_line(data = df, aes(x = P, y = D)))

    df <- data.frame(D = c(D_valve1, D_valve1), P = c(PTD_valve1, PK_valve1))

    plot(plot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = P, y = D)) +
      geom_line(data = df, aes(x = P, y = D)))

    Final_table(data.frame(
      depth = D_valve1,
      Pc = PK_valve1,
      Pt = PTD_valve1
    ))

    dvalve <- D_valve1
    PTDvalve <- PTD_valve1
    Pcvalve <- PK_valve1
    D_valve <- D_valve1
    PTD_valve <- PTD_valve1


    while (dvalve < D_operating_point) {
      dvalve <- (PTDvalve - input$Pso - dvalve * input$GL) / (Gc - input$GL)
      Pcvalve <- input$Pso + Gc * dvalve
      if (dvalve < D_operating_point) {
        df <- data.frame(D = c(D_valve, dvalve), P = c(PTD_valve, Pcvalve))
        plot(plot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = P, y = D)) +
          geom_line(data = df, aes(x = P, y = D)))

        PTDvalve <- Gtd * dvalve + Pwh_design

        df <- data.frame(D = c(dvalve, dvalve), P = c(PTDvalve, Pcvalve))
        plot(plot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = P, y = D)) +
          geom_line(data = df, aes(x = P, y = D)))


        valve <- c(dvalve, Pcvalve, PTDvalve)
        Final_table(rbind(Final_table(), valve))
        D_valve <- dvalve
        PTD_valve <- PTDvalve
      }
    }

    valve <- c(D_operating_point, P_operating_point_casing, P_operating_point_formation)
    Final_table(rbind(Final_table(), valve))


    GTemp <- (input$Tres - input$Twh) / input$Dmax

    CT_data <- data.frame(Temp = c(61:300), Ct = c(0.998, 0.996, 0.994, 0.991, 0.989, 0.987, 0.985, 0.983, 0.981, 0.979, 0.977, 0.975, 0.973, 0.971, 0.969, 0.967, 0.965, 0.963, 0.961, 0.959, 0.957, 0.955, 0.953, 0.951, 0.949, 0.947, 0.945, 0.943, 0.941, 0.939, 0.938, 0.936, 0.934, 0.932, 0.93, 0.928, 0.926, 0.924, 0.923, 0.921, 0.919, 0.917, 0.915, 0.914, 0.912, 0.91, 0.908, 0.906, 0.905, 0.903, 0.901, 0.899, 0.898, 0.896, 0.894, 0.893, 0.891, 0.889, 0.887, 0.886, 0.884, 0.882, 0.881, 0.879, 0.877, 0.876, 0.874, 0.872, 0.871, 0.869, 0.686, 0.866, 0.864, 0.863, 0.861, 0.86, 0.858, 0.856, 0.855, 0.853, 0.852, 0.85, 0.849, 0.847, 0.845, 0.844, 0.842, 0.841, 0.839, 0.838, 0.836, 0.835, 0.833, 0.832, 0.83, 0.829, 0.827, 0.826, 0.825, 0.823, 0.822, 0.82, 0.819, 0.817, 0.816, 0.814, 0.813, 0.812, 0.81, 0.809, 0.807, 0.806, 0.805, 0.803, 0.802, 0.8, 0.799, 0.798, 0.796, 0.795, 0.794, 0.792, 0.791, 0.79, 0.788, 0.787, 0.786, 0.784, 0.783, 0.782, 0.78, 0.779, 0.778, 0.776, 0.775, 0.774, 0.772, 0.771, 0.77, 0.769, 0.767, 0.766, 0.765, 0.764, 0.762, 0.761, 0.76, 0.759, 0.757, 0.756, 0.755, 0.754, 0.752, 0.751, 0.75, 0.749, 0.748, 0.746, 0.745, 0.744, 0.743, 0.742, 0.74, 0.739, 0.738, 0.737, 0.736, 0.735, 0.733, 0.732, 0.731, 0.73, 0.729, 0.728, 0.727, 0.725, 0.724, 0.723, 0.722, 0.721, 0.72, 0.719, 0.718, 0.717, 0.715, 0.714, 0.713, 0.712, 0.711, 0.71, 0.709, 0.708, 0.707, 0.706, 0.705, 0.704, 0.702, 0.701, 0.7, 0.699, 0.698, 0.697, 0.696, 0.695, 0.694, 0.693, 0.692, 0.691, 0.69, 0.689, 0.688, 0.687, 0.686, 0.685, 0.684, 0.683, 0.682, 0.681, 0.68, 0.679, 0.678, 0.677, 0.676, 0.675, 0.674, 0.673, 0.672, 0.671, 0.67, 0.699, 0.668, 0.667, 0.666, 0.665, 0.664, 0.663, 0.662, 0.662, 0.661, 0.66))


    Final_table(Final_table() %>% mutate(
      Pbt = Pc * (1 - input$R) + Pt * input$R,
      TEMP = input$Twh + GTemp * depth,
      Temp = ceiling(TEMP)
    ))
    Final_table(merge(x = Final_table(), y = CT_data, by = "Temp", all.x = T))
    Final_table(Final_table() %>% select(depth, Pc, Pt, Pbt, TEMP, Ct))

    Final_table(Final_table() %>% mutate(
      Pb = Pbt * Ct,
      Pvo = Pb / (1 - input$R)
    ))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot()
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    Final_table()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I followed ur instructions and now the interface at least show but when i press the action button it gives error:Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
  1: runApp
I know u perhaps need the server so i will add it to the post

Comment: the UI is the same as in ur answer and the code before adding to the app works perfectly

Comment: The error comes when you create `Final_table(data.frame(
      depth = D_valve1,
      Pc = PK_valve1,
      Pt = PTD_valve1
    ))` PTD_valve1 is of length 0. All dataframe columns must have equal number of rows.

Comment: but i already assigned it a value in '  PTD_valve1=Gtd*D_valve1+Pwh_design'  two rows above why it doesn't accept it

Comment: In approx line 74, `Gc <- (input$Pso - input$Pcs) / (0 - input$D1)` has `input$Pcs` that doesn't exist. Perhaps you meant `input$Psc`.

Comment: @YousefYahia Check my edit, It runs without errors now. Is the output correct?

Comment: The plot from ur answer messed up really but back to my app it seems working but it doesn't show the plot or the table nor it gives an error and i corrected the Pcs thing

Comment: My app somehow worked finally thanks a lot for ur help i have been an annoyance the last couple of days